# How to pass a formula from one workbook to another so it displays results?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer formulas from one workbook to another.

Once the formulas are transferred, they show up in the cells as formulas, instead of the results of their calculations.

The workbooks and sheets:

```vb
Set wb = Workbooks("Main.xlsm")
Set wsh = wb.Worksheets("Positions")
Set wbF = Workbooks("Formulas.xlsx")
Set wshF = wbF.Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

The formulas worksheet looks like this:
[image]

The code is this:

```vb
Sub EnterFormulasFromFormulasSheet()
    ' This sub enters all the formulas into all the rows after the entries were done in the Form Options2Entry
    ' there is a Totals row thatis the last row of the range, thereforeneed to find last row,
    ' insert a blank row there and then do the entries intothat newblank row
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("Main.xlsm")
    Set wsh = wb.Worksheets("Positions")
    Set wbF = Workbooks("Formulas.xlsx")
    Set wshF = wbF.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    With wsh
       ' Last Row Number is ir because there is a Total row which is the last row and the working row is inserted above it
        ' this isdone in the FormEntry form module
       RealLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
       'Range("A" & RealLastRow).EntireRow.Insert ' The actual insertion takes place in the FormEnry form
       ir = RealLastRow - 1 ' after the insertion last (Total) row moves down,
                                       'but variable RealLastRow stays where the now inserted row is
                                       'this applies to the form because that's where the row is inserted, no insertion here though
    End With

   
   ' In order to make the worksheet dynamic,all the cells must contain formula,not just calculated results
   
  Set rngF = wshF.Range("A1:C51")
  Dim count As Long
  Dim colF As String
  Dim FormulaString As String

  For count = 1 To 51
    If wshF.Cells(count, "C") <> "" Then
        colF = wshF.Cells(count, "A").Value
        FormulaString = wshF.Cells(count, "C")
        FormulaString = Replace(FormulaString, Chr(126), Chr(34)) 'this replaces every instance of the tilde with a double quote.
        FormulaString = Replace(FormulaString, "|", ir) ' this replaces | with ir
        wsh.Cells(ir, colF).Formula = FormulaString
     End If
  Next count
End Sub
```

The code produces this result in the Main workbook:
[image]

When I go through the code step by step the final step:

`wsh.Cells(ir, colF).Formula = FormulaString`

shows FormulaString formatted properly like this:

"=IF($C9=0,"",$I9/$H9)"

I tried using double quotes at beginning and end, but it made no difference.

Comment: Do you say that the formula is correct, but it does not act as a formula, you can see it as a string? If yes, please format the range where the formula should be placed as `General`, **before placing it**. If not, please better describe what happens against what you need. It can happen that, if the range where the formula is placed was already formatted as `Text`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but setting the cells in the worksheet to General did not help. What I I need is for the formula to act as a formula instead of just showing in the cell as a string.  When I click on the cell the formula shows up perfectly in the formula bar, the same as all the native formulas, it just does not do what it's supposed to.

Comment: Please, create a test Sub with a single line, activate a cell (formatted as General) and run the next code line: `"ActiveCell.Formula = "=Today()"`.  Do you see the formula string or today date? Please, do it in the sheet where your code writes formulas...

Comment: Do the formulas in your setup sheet have any leading spaces, or a single-quote to tell Excel they are text not formulas?  Maybe try `FormulaString = Trim(wshF.Cells(count, "C").Value)`  FYI pretty sure you do not need that tilde/quote replacement - no problem with just putting the quotes in your formula template.

Comment: FaneDuru , thanks I tried it and it does show up as a data

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, that worked like a charm. when you look at the column it's hard to tell there is an extra space at the front. Great thinking, thank you. the tilde/quote replacement just makes it easier for me if I have an empty string at the end of the formula. the double triple quotes drive me nuts. Thanks again for your help. Now I have no excuse but to get back to work. 

Comment: You don't need to double-up quotes unless you're defining them in VBA.  `=""` is perfectly fine when stored as text in a cell, so I'd find it easier to read than `=~~`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim strFormula As String

strFormula = "=ROUND(A3,0)"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Working).Range("A4").Formula = strFormula
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?